# How can I configure the keyboard layout for the FileVault 2 unlock screen?

Tags: keyboard, filevault

I installed Mac OS X Lion and enabled FileVault to have a full disk encryption of my system disk. I bought my Mac with a French keyboard (since I'm French and used to this layout) but my Mac is configured to be in English, except for the keyboard layout.

However, after enabling FileVault, my Mac rebooted and I was greeted with the FileVault unlock screen and asked for my password. I entered it, and was told it was incorrect. After many try, I suspected that the keyboard layout was not French but US. I managed to enter my keyboard with this mapping and it was accepted (I'm lucky that I know enough of the Us keyboard layout to do that).

I went to the System Preferences, but I didn't see an option to change the keyboard layout on the FileVault unlock screen. Nor did I see an option to changed it when I was blocked at the prompt.

So, I'm wondering how can I change the keyboard layout of the FileVault unlock screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works.

*System Preferences* -> *Login* -> **Login Options** -> **Check** *Enable Show Input menu in login window*

[image: Enable Show Input menu in login window]

Comment: The language menu on the boot screen appears in the top right corner of the screen, which is not immediately visible and can be difficult to find. I only found it after looking at the screens from https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/enabling-filevault-2-pre-boot-login-screen-functions-from-the-command-line/.

Comment: The question was answered in 2011 for OS X Lion.

Comment: Here is [an updated answer for macOS 10.15 Catalina](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-macos-login-keyboard-layout.html).